# Email Address Fields in Sendable DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, send-email

Can you please respond to following query. If there are multiple email addresses in a Sendable DE, and one of them is Subscriber key, will the email be always send to the Subscriber Key (Email Address).

Answer (score 3):

Your SubscriberKey should be of Text datatype and you should only have one field of EmailAddress datatype. When sending to a Sendable DE like that, the email will be sent to the address in the EmailAddress type field, if the subscriber has not been sent to from your account before. If the subscriber has previously been sent to, the value in the EmailAddress field is ignored and the email address from All Subscribers is used.

Triggered Sends operate slightly differently in that with the correct configuration, the email address from from your API call/Data Extension EmailAddress field is used to override All Subscribers for existing subscribers.

Comment: Nice.  This is an important (and undocumented AFAIK) nuance to consider -- especially when dealing with integrated systems that could have multiple email addresses for a single subscriber.

Comment: It's a painful design consideration, for sure!

Answer (score 1):

I just tested what you described and found that the system actually updated the All Subscribers list with the values in the EmailAddress field.  Emails were received at the email address in this EmailAddress field.

Comment: Hi Jessica, is your email field called "EmailAddress"? Because I'm currently experiencing the opposite: the All Subscribers list is not updated. Due to our Salesforce integration the email field is called "Email" as is standard in Salesforce Sales Cloud